# Can't Pass the postion of a listview to second activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

hi I created a database which store some edit texts. I have three activities A, B, and C. Activity A shows the stored values in List View. when click on the List View item in Activity A, it passes its position and stored data to Activity B, where Activity B show this as a simple text and can't be edit. Now I want to pass this data from activity B to Activity C where it can edit. How can I pass the list view position from A to C through Acitvity B.

Activity A

```
public class UserActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListAdapter users;
    private ListView lista;
    private AccessModel data;
    private ArrayList<User> query;
    private LinearLayout empty_data;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.listusers);
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstusers);
        empty_data= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.empty_data);
        data = new AccessModel(this);       
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();       
         query = data.listUser();

         if(query.size()>0)
           empty_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         else
           empty_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         users = new ListAdapter(this, query);
         lista.setAdapter(users);
         lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optionsbar, menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.adduser:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterUser.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;                
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        User u = (User) query.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(UserActivity.this, ViewPatientData.class);
        i.putExtra(getString(R.string.valuesId), String.valueOf(u.getId()));
        startActivity(i);       
    }




}
```

Activity B

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_patient_data);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        data = new AccessModel(this);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_age);
        gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_gender);
        height = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_height);
        weight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_weight);
        dateofbirth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dateofbirth);
        religion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_religion);
        maritalstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_maritalstatus);
        dateofadmission = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dateofadmission);
        address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        contact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contact);
        emergencycontact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_emergencycontact);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        occupation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_occupation);
        bloodtype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_bloodtype);
        refferedvia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_refferedvia);

        btnedit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btedit);
        btnedit.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Bundle v = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(v==null){
            back();
            return;
        }

        userId = v.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));     
        loadData(userId);

    }

    private void loadData(String id){

            User u = (User) data.getUser(id);
            Toast.makeText(this, u.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            name.setText(u.getName().toString());           
            age.setText(u.getAge());
            gender.setText(u.getGender());
            height.setText(u.getHeight());
            weight.setText(u.getWeight());
            dateofbirth.setText(u.getDateofbirth());
            religion.setText(u.getReligion());          
            maritalstatus.setText(u.getMaritalstatus());
            dateofadmission.setText(u.getDateofadmission());
            contact.setText(u.getContact());
            emergencycontact.setText(u.getEmergencycontact());
            email.setText(u.getEmail());
            occupation.setText(u.getOccupation());          
            bloodtype.setText(u.getBloodtype());
            refferedvia.setText(u.getRefferedvia());
            address.setText(u.getAddress());

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btedit:


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                back();
                return true;                
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void back(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Acitivity C

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Bundle v = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(v==null){
            back();
            return;
        }

        userId = v.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));     
        loadData(userId);

    }

    private void loadData(String id){

            User u = (User) data.getUser(id);
            Toast.makeText(this, u.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            name.setText(u.getName().toString());           
            age.setText(u.getAge());
            gender.setText(u.getGender());
            height.setText(u.getHeight());
            weight.setText(u.getWeight());
            dateofbirth.setText(u.getDateofbirth());
            religion.setText(u.getReligion());          
            maritalstatus.setText(u.getMaritalstatus());
            dateofadmission.setText(u.getDateofadmission());
            contact.setText(u.getContact());
            emergencycontact.setText(u.getEmergencycontact());
            email.setText(u.getEmail());
            occupation.setText(u.getOccupation());          
            bloodtype.setText(u.getBloodtype());
            refferedvia.setText(u.getRefferedvia());
            address.setText(u.getAddress());


    }


    private void updateUser(String id){
        String[] ids = {id};
        try{
            data.updateUser(ids,name.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString(), gender.getText().toString(), height.getText().toString(), weight.getText().toString(), dateofbirth.getText().toString()
                    ,religion.getText().toString(), maritalstatus.getText().toString(), dateofadmission.getText().toString(), address.getText().toString(), contact.getText().toString(), emergencycontact.getText().toString()
                    ,email.getText().toString(), occupation.getText().toString(), bloodtype.getText().toString(), refferedvia.getText().toString());                        
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.good), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }

    private void deleteUser(String id){
        String[] ids = {id};
        try{
            data.deleteUser(ids);                       
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.good), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            back();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btupdate:
            updateUser(userId);
            break;
        case R.id.btdelete:
            deleteUser(userId);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                back();
                return true;                
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void back(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the answer. It's very similar to the id extra you added to the intent in Activity B.

In A, do the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra(getString(R.string.valuesId), String.valueOf(u.getId()));
i.putExtra("position", position);
```

In B, extract this as:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int position = extras.getInt("position");
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
i.putExtra(getString(R.string.valuesId), String.valueOf(u.getId()));
i.putExtra("position", position);
```

In C, extract the position as before:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int position = extras.getInt("position");
```

Comment: why? this is the way Android expects you to pass data between activities

Comment: Please see the above edit codes and tell me where to place these codes you have provided

Comment: The lines go just before you do startActivity(i). So in A, it will be inside the onItemClick() method. In B and C, it will be in the back() method. Just add the lines of code that I've written and you do not already have and you should be good to go.

Comment: not working for me..still giving errors...in activity B I have to put this code after 
        case R.id.btedit:
and I think in activity C back() method is not the right place seems to me... may be its in the resume activity????

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the value from the intent bundle in Activity B in a variable, and then pass that value in the new intent bundle that goes to Activity C