# Passing item position of listview from database through 2nd activity

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

hi I created a diary where one can save their notes. I have 3 activities let's say A, B and C activity. now I save the edited notes in Activity A in list view and when click on item position it goes to Activity B showing me the TextView form what I have entered in the edited boxes. now in Activity B showing me the TextView notes along with a edit button where I can edit or update the same data in Activity C. So I want that when I click on edit/update button in Activity B, it pass the item position of list saved in Activity A. In short I want to pass item position from A to C through Activity B. I can successfully pass from A to B but can't from B to C. please provide the code so it will be easy to me. here is some code.

Activity A

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.listusers);
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstusers);
        empty_data= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.empty_data);
        data = new AccessModel(this);       
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();       
         query = data.listUser();

         if(query.size()>0)
           empty_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         else
           empty_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         users = new ListAdapter(this, query);
         lista.setAdapter(users);
         lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        User u = (User) query.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        i.putExtra(getString(R.string.valuesId), String.valueOf(u.getId()));
        i.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(i);       
    }



    }
```

here is Activity B

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Bundle v = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(v==null){
            back();
            return;
        }

        userId = v.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));     
        loadData(userId);

    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btedit:
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            int position = extras.getInt("position");
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
            i.putExtra("position", position);   
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

here is Activity C

```
    data = new AccessModel(this);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mn_name);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mn_age);
        gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mn_gender);
        height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mn_height);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mn_weight);
        dateofbirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mn_dob);

        btnupdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btupdate);
        btndelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btdelete);               

        btnupdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btndelete.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras==null){
            back();
            return;
        }

        userId = extras.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));        
        loadData(userId);

    }

    private void loadData(String id){

            User u = (User) data.getUser(id);
            Toast.makeText(this, u.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            name.setText(u.getName().toString());           
            age.setText(u.getAge());
            gender.setText(u.getGender());
            height.setText(u.getHeight());
            weight.setText(u.getWeight());
            dateofbirth.setText(u.getDateofbirth());        
    }


    private void updateUser(String id){
        String[] ids = {id};
        try{
            data.updateUser(ids,name.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString(), gender.getText().toString(), height.getText().toString(), weight.getText().toString(), dateofbirth.getText().toString());  

            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.good), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }

    private void deleteUser(String id){
        String[] ids = {id};
        try{
            data.deleteUser(ids);                       
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.good), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            back();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btupdate:
            updateUser(userId);
            break;
        case R.id.btdelete:
            deleteUser(userId);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                back();
                return true;                
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void back(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096407/cant-pass-the-postion-of-a-listview-to-second-activity

Comment: the answer is not given to me.. please give me the correct answer. what I did wrong in activity b under edit button, after clicking edit, app crashes

Comment: Where do you get the position in C?

Comment: ok I edited activity c. now have a look at activity c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple.

In Activity B right pass string like

```
i.putExtra("message", userId);
```

and in Activity C, get this one

```
userId  = extras.getString("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "position" from `B` to `C` , but reading `userId = extras.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));` in `C` ...

I guess `B` should pass `userId` to `C` and not `position` ?!?!?

Update:
Activity B:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btedit:
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            int position = extras.getInt("position");
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);

            // You pass "position" here
            i.putExtra("position", position);   
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

So you pass "position" to Activity C, but in Activity C you read:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras==null){
            back();
            return;
        }

        // Here you don't read "position" but R.string.valuesId ?!?!?!?
        userId = extras.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));        
        loadData(userId);

    }
```

Comment: so how to do this? give me a simple code either way from a to c through b or from b to c.

Comment: Wait, read your code again! In `B` you do `i.putExtra("position", position);  ` and in C you read `extras.getString(getString(R.string.valuesId));` ...

Comment: that is how I pass from a to b.

Comment: come on , have a look at `onClick()` of `Activity B`. What data are you putting into the intent extra? --> "position"     Next have a look at `onResume()` of Activity C where you read intent extra --> "R.string.valuesId" ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69749/discussion-between-user3866627-and-sockeqwe).

Comment: are you kidding me? Who has written your code? `extras.getInt("position")`

Comment: I got this from other person.

Comment: Then learn java and android before posting. btw. To get the position in C do that: `extras.getInt("position")`